# Filter by multiple values on the same column

Tags: sql, attributes, opencart, conditional-statements, where-clause

What follows is a simplified version of the tables and the task itself, if it's
of any help the actual tables are from the Opencart's database, so what I want
to achieve is to filter products in store by manufacturer and attributes. All I need is a hint to how this can be achieved in sql not necessarily opencart specific. Trying to learn SQL so please don't advise using modules.

Tables:

```
product
-------------------
ID name description manufacturer_id
0  n0   desc0       33
1  n1   desc1       56
2  n2   desc2       68

product_attribute
-------------------
pID ID text
0   12 red 
0   13 xl
1   12 red
1   13 xs
2   13 xxl
```

SQL to filter the products by manufacturer and attribute, the condition between 
attribute groups (ex. 'color, size, ..') should be AND, the condition between 
the attributes of the same group (ex. 'color') should be OR. Say I want to get
the products that have the manufacturer (33 OR 56) AND color 'red OR green' and a size of 'xl OR xxl':

```
---------------
Manufacurer
    ✓ 33
    ✓ 56
    o 68

Color
    ✓ red
    ✓ green

Size
    ✓ xl
    o xs
    ✓ xxl
---------------

SELECT p.ID
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON (pa.pID = p.ID)
WHERE p.manufacturer_id = 33 OR p.manufacturer_id = 56
AND   pa.text = red OR pa.text = green
AND   pa.text = xl  OR pa.text = xxl
```

Should return:

```
result table
--------------
ID
0
```

Comment: The [solution fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cabe8d/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logicals operations have priorities like in regular math.

The `AND` operator has the priority over the `OR` the same way the multiplication has priority over the addition.

Also, since you're working with strings, don't forget to use double or simples quotes.

```
p.manufacturer_id = 33 OR p.manufacturer_id = 56
AND   pa.text = "red" OR pa.text = "green"
AND   pa.text = "xl"  OR pa.text = "xxl"
```

Will provide the same result than

```
p.manufacturer_id = 33
OR (p.manufacturer_id = 56 AND pa.text = "red")
OR (pa.text = "green" AND pa.text = "xl")
OR pa.text = "xxl"
```

I suppose the result of your query in your example is

```
result table
--------------
ID
0
1
2
```

I suggest you to use parenthesis to make sure your conditions are well respected.

```
(p.manufacturer_id = 33 OR p.manufacturer_id = 56)
AND (pa.text = "red" OR pa.text = "green")
AND (pa.text = "xl"  OR pa.text = "xxl")
```

The above query won't work, because for an unique entry, if `(pa.text = "red" OR pa.text = "green")` is true, then `(pa.text = "xl"  OR pa.text = "xxl")` will be false (since pa.text value is already "red" or "green")

Since you need entries that have red or green color AND xl or xxl size, you can search for the entries that have 2 of thoses **I assume that a product can't be green and red at the same time and can't have 2 differents sizes**

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON (pa.pID = p.ID)
WHERE (p.manufacturer_id = 33 OR p.manufacturer_id = 56)
AND pa.text IN ("red", "green", "xl", "xxl")
GROUP by pa.text
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Result

```
ID
--
1
```

1 because I tested it with MySQL and it starts the auto incremented indexes with 1.

[Test it yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad9d3/29)

Comment: I tried this structure before, it returns nothing. This must be related to the fact that a given ROW x COLUMN cannot have different values at the same time (`AND(pa.text = red ....  AND(pa.text = xl`). So it must be a different way to filter for multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`:

```
WHERE p.manufacturer_id IN (33, 56) AND
      pa.text IN ('red', 'green') AND
      pa.size IN ('xl', 'xxl')
```

You also need single quotes around the string constants.

EDIT:

Based on your edit, I think you want:

```
select pa.pid
from product_attribute pa join
     product p
     on p.id = pa.pid and p.manufacturer_id in (33, 56)
where (pa.id = 12 and pa.text in ('red', 'green')) or
      (pa.id = 13 and pa.text in ('xl', 'xxl'))
group by pa.pid
having count(distinct pa.id) = 2  -- both match
```

Comment: there is no `pa.size` column, only `pa.text` to make an attribute unique I use `CONCAT(pa.ID, pa.text)` so following your example I should use somethinng like
    `WHERE p.manufacturer_id IN (33, 56) AND
        CONCAT(pa.ID, pa.text) IN ('12red', '12green') AND
        CONCAT(pa.ID, pa.text) IN ('13xl', '13xxl')` 

but that as well returns nothing.

Comment: The updated answer seems to work, the only thing that needs to be changed is `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` to `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` , since I may have more attribute groups and more attributes in a group, is that right?

Comment: @AlexTofan `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` will work for 2 or more, but it might provide unexpected results. better use `HAVING COUNT(*) = MyNumberOfAttributes`

Comment: @Cid after testing with more attribute groups I can say you are right about that, so I updated the [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cabe8d/4) to use `HAVING COUNT(*) = NumberOfAttributeGroups` , thanks.